# Fragment back-stack management on android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have several fragments. They transition using slid-in animations. MainFragment-> Fragment2 -> Fragment3.

1) I want to clear backstack when user reach MainFragment, leaving just that fragment in the stack.

2) In some cases I want to remove the previous item in the stack. Say when user press back button and move from fragment3 = > fragment2.

I have shown my code below. If I use that method, the fragment transitions animations get messed up. I am not sure how to implement the second requirement.

Another question is when I remove fragments from backstack do they get disposed?

```
private void replace(Fragment fragment )    
{
if(fragment == null) return;

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_enter,
                    R.anim.fragment_exit);

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());

            fragmentTransaction.commit();


            if(fragment instanceof MainFragment)
                clearBackStack();
}
```

---

```
public void clearBackStack() {

        if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding, simpler than you think. Here I am calling the `add` method of `FragmentTransaction`. From Google sample code @ [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and using your code as sample:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.add(R.id.fragment, fragment3);
transaction.addToBackStack(fragment3.toString());

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Note:  The **add** method does not replace/remove fragment2 as the previous fragment. Call `transaction.add` with **fragment3** after using or adding **fragment2**. Therefore the **back key** will show fragment2 when fragment3 is displayed.

Comment: Based on your reference "For example, here's how you can replace one fragment with another, and preserve the previous state in the back stack:"
i think I need to use replace.

Comment: @pats, In your case, it's probably better for you to call the add method, as I stated above. I gave the reference as good documentation and comparison. If you "add" fragment3 after using or adding fragment2, then back key will show fragment2. I'll update my notes to make that clear.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tired add(), but it did not change the fragment. It was stuck on MainFragment. My objective here is to when we reach Mainfragment from any path, the entire back-stack has to be wiped out. But the fragment traditions should work as intended.

Comment: have issue with fragment stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652142/stack-management-issue-with-navigation-drawer